How to replace pattern in last line
I'm trying to replace "}," by "}" from the last line of a file :
My /etc/firefox/policies/policies.json file like this because I added the certificate lines using a for loop :
$ cat /etc/firefox/policies/policies.json
{
  "policies": {
    "Certificates": {
      "Install": [
        {"cert1.der", "/home/username/cert1.pem"},
        {"cert2.der", "/home/username/cert2.pem"},
$ 

Please note there no "\n" at the end of this file (yet).
Before adding this to the end of my JSON file :
      ]
    }
  }
}

, how can I remove the last , : replacing "}," by "}" for example ?
sed seems a complicated solution to do that according to this solution.
Is there a more readable solution using awk or perl ?

You should restore previous file and fix your code

@steeldriver Great :+1, It's just past 8pm in France, so I'll  try your solution tomorrow :).

To generate the given JSON from a list of pathnames of .pem files, you may use jq and its reduce() functionality to build up the array:
jq -n 'reduce $ARGS.positional[] as $pathname ({}; 
    .policies.Certificates.Install += [[
        ($pathname | rtrimstr(".pem") + ".der" | sub(".*/";"")), 
        $pathname
    ]])' --args /home/username/cert1.pem /home/username/cert2.pem /home/username/cert-B.pem

Given the pathnames at the end of the command (which could be an expansion of some filename globbing pattern, such as ~username/*.pem), the list of pathnames ($ARGS.positional) is added one by one to the Install array.  We also strip the .pem filename suffix and the directory path to create the corresponding .der string.
The command above would generate the following JSON:
{
  "policies": {
    "Certificates": {
      "Install": [
        [
          "cert1.der",
          "/home/username/cert1.pem"
        ],
        [
          "cert2.der",
          "/home/username/cert2.pem"
        ],
        [
          "cert-B.der",
          "/home/username/cert-B.pem"
        ]
      ]
    }
  }
}

(Note that {"cert1.der","/home/username/cert1.pem"} is valid JSON, but is equivalent to {"cert1.der":null,"/home/username/cert1.pem":null}, which is unlikely what you want.)
If you would want to add this to an already existing JSON document, then just replace the {} in the reduce() call with input and pass the name of the file to the jq command before the --args option or on the command's standard input stream:
$ cat my-file.json
{
  "name": "Sebastian",
  "policies": {
    "Certificates": {
      "Install": [
        [
          "certX.der",
          "/home/username/certX.pem"
        ]
      ]
    }
  }
}

Feeding the existing JSON document on standard input with a redirection:
$ jq -n 'reduce $ARGS.positional[] as $pathname (input; .policies.Certificates.Install += [[ ($pathname | rtrimstr(".pem") + ".der" | sub(".*/";"")), $pathname ]])' --args /home/username/cert1.pem /home/username/cert2.pem /home/username/cert-B.pem <my-file.json
{
  "name": "Sebastian",
  "policies": {
    "Certificates": {
      "Install": [
        [
          "certX.der",
          "/home/username/certX.pem"
        ],
        [
          "cert1.der",
          "/home/username/cert1.pem"
        ],
        [
          "cert2.der",
          "/home/username/cert2.pem"
        ],
        [
          "cert-B.der",
          "/home/username/cert-B.pem"
        ]
      ]
    }
  }
}

Or passing the name of the file on jq's command line:
$ jq -n 'reduce $ARGS.positional[] as $pathname (input; .policies.Certificates.Install += [[ ($pathname | rtrimstr(".pem") + ".der" | sub(".*/";"")), $pathname ]])' my-file.json --args /home/username/cert1.pem /home/username/cert2.pem /home/username/cert-B.pem
{
  "name": "Sebastian",
  "policies": {
    "Certificates": {
      "Install": [
        [
          "certX.der",
          "/home/username/certX.pem"
        ],
        [
          "cert1.der",
          "/home/username/cert1.pem"
        ],
        [
          "cert2.der",
          "/home/username/cert2.pem"
        ],
        [
          "cert-B.der",
          "/home/username/cert-B.pem"
        ]
      ]
    }
  }
}


Amazing, thanks !


I'm trying to replace }, by } from the last line of a file...
sed seems a complicated solution to do that...

Actually, I would say sed is the easiest tool to do that with, since in sed, you know the last line is the last line already when processing it. AFAIK it's not that simple in awk and Perl, where you process the line and then whoops, jump to the END block. That means you manually need to buffer one line...
But in sed, it's just this:
sed -e '$s/},/}/'

Though you might want to do the change only at the end of the line, in case there's another in the middle:
sed -e '$s/},[[:space:]]*$/}/'


In Perl, you'd do:
perl -pe 's/},/}/ if eof'


Keep that answer, as it is neat and well explained :) (I didn't notice the comment you refer to)

"AFAIK it's not that simple in awk and Perl" --> Perl has eof, for example perl -ne 'print if eof' is same as tail -n1

@Sundeep, aahh, thank you, I've missed that.

Using any awk and only storing 2 lines at a time in memory:
$ awk 'NR>1{print p} {p=$0} END{sub(/,$/,"\n      ]\n    }\n  }\n}",p); print p}' file
{
  "policies": {
    "Certificates": {
      "Install": [
        {"cert1.der", "/home/username/cert1.pem"},
        {"cert2.der", "/home/username/cert2.pem"}
      ]
    }
  }
}

or GNU awk for multi-char RS and reading the whole file into memory at once:
$ awk -v RS='^$' '{sub(/,\n$/,"\n      ]\n    }\n  }\n}")} 1' file
{
  "policies": {
    "Certificates": {
      "Install": [
        {"cert1.der", "/home/username/cert1.pem"},
        {"cert2.der", "/home/username/cert2.pem"}
      ]
    }
  }
}


Generating and processing JSON is generally easier with a proper programming language than with a shell as generally they can just generate JSON data from their own data structures¹.
Some of those language interpreters such as perl are easily called from a shell though:
$ touch cert{1,2}.pem
$ perl -MJSON::PP -e '
  $o->{policies}->{Certificates}->{Install} =
    [map [s{.*/(.*)\.pem}{$1.der}r, $_], @ARGV];
  print JSON::PP->new->indent->indent_length(2)->
        space_after->encode($o)' -- ~/*.pem
{
  "policies": {
    "Certificates": {
      "Install": [
        [
          "cert1.der",
          "/home/chazelas/cert1.pem"
        ],
        [
          "cert2.der",
          "/home/chazelas/cert2.pem"
        ]
      ]
    }
  }
}

Using perl's JSON module in object oriented mode has the advantage of being able to process arbitrary .pem file paths (even if that means the result will not necessarily be valid UTF-8). python could also be used for that.
Merging an existing file.json file with those is equally trivial as it's just a matter of decodeing that JSON into a perl data structure, updating that data structure in the same way, and encodeing it again to generate the new JSON.

¹ Strictly speaking and anecdotally, the ksh93 shell has some experimental support for complex data structures and the last beta version before the team that was maintaining it at AT&T was disbanded and ksh93 development was carried on as a community effort even had support for representing them as JSON. But that prove too buggy and that effort was abandoned.
